# ALPR on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, pi-2

I'm looking to do a quickie - that is, a simple project for ALPR on the Raspberry Pi.  I would prefer to have the ALPR engine on the Raspberry Pi so that I don't have to send images over to the cloud.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

What great timing!  We are excited to announced our ALPR SDK on Raspberry Pi.  Depending on the size of your project, you may be able to get away with our Free Trial.  You can read more about our ALPR SDK for the Raspberry Pi) in our blog: https://platerecognizer.com/blog/alpr-on-raspberry-pi/.  And from there, you can get the Free Trial to start your project.